# How to retrieve the content (with a specific ID) via ajax by clicking a link tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, content, id

I want to retrieve the content with the specific ID via ajax post method.

For instance, if I click a link tag which has a specific post ID, the content of that ID will load into the **post-data** div.

I am very new to wp ajax and could someone help me to achieve this?

Here is my codes
**HTML a tag**

```
<a id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="#">This is link</a> 
<!-- the content -->
<div id="post-data"></div>
```

**Jquery Ajax**

```
    $("a").click(function (event) {
    var post_ID = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        action: "my_custom_data",
        data: {post_link: post_ID},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#post-data').append(response);
        }
    });
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
```

**WP Action**

```
   add_action('wp_ajax_my_custom_data', 'my_custom_data');
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_data', 'my_custom_data');

   function my_custom_data(){
   $post_link = data['post_link'];
   echo get_the_content($post_link);
   die();
   }
```

I think something is wrong with my codes, I just get the response 0.

Comment: the "action" must go in datas : `"data" : {"post_link" : post_ID, "action" : "my_custom_data"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the action in the post data

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  type:"POST",
       data: { 
       action: "my_custom_data",
       post_link: post_ID
},
success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('#post-data').append(response);
    }
});
   return false;
.....
```

Then use $_POST['post_link']  in your PHP

```
   function my_custom_data(){
       $post_link = $_POST['post_link'];
   echo get_the_content($post_link);
   die();
   }
```